# MySql query to get records having id contained into vba array

Tags: mysql, vba

I write a MySql query with the code below to get records with ids contained in an array.

It works, but is there any better way to do it ? (instead of multiple "OR")

```
myArr = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
SqlStr = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id ='"
For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
    SqlStr = SqlStr & myArr(i, 1) & "' OR id ='"
Next i
SqlStr = Left(SqlStr, Len(SqlStr) - 7)
```

I hope that the question is not silly: I'm trying to improve myself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the code to include the **IN** Operator, it will still loop, but not have several OR's

```
Dim inVar As String
myArr = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value

SqlStr = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN ("

For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
    inVar = inVar & ",'" & myArr(i, 1) & "'"
Next i

SqlStr = SqlStr & Right(inVar, Len(inVar) - 2) & ")"
```

The sequence would be like,

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN ('1', '2')`

Comment: Thanks, I think is better using "in", isn't it?

Comment: It has its advantage of being easier to debug and read, minimizing the long lines of code if there are larger data to be used. It is similar to a complex/compound OR. Just neater and simpler. Execution wise, I would still think IN is better. However I am not ***100%*** sure about it.

Comment: I would `... & replace$(myArr(i, 1), "'", "''") & ...` just to be safe from injection